# Metric datasource с годными интеграцией в Grafana и Debezium коннектором

Tags: spring, storage, prometheus, grafana

Сейчас на проекте мы используем ***Grafana + Prometheus + наш кастомный сервис на Spring-e***, который собирает метрики с ***DWH*** и ***Data lake-ов***, проворачивает свою логику и пушит показатели в ***Prometheus***.

**Проблема:** *При накате обновления нашего кастомного сервиса, дропаются метрики в Prometheus и летят мильярды ненужных алертов.*

Посоветуйте БД для хранения метрик, у которых есть интеграция с Grafana, их легко подружить  с Spring Data и Debezium-oм. Было бы очень круто, если есть решение не на БД временных рядов.

Comment: Ну летят алерты и пусть себе летят, в чём проблема-то? Я не понял. В том же Alertmanager есть возможность временно заглушить алерты если надо, да и в Grafana тоже

Comment: На enSO про алерты есть такое: [dont alert using prometheus/alertmanager at particular time (maintance window) if machine goes down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718859)

Comment: В добавок к алертам, есть необходимость в хранении данных в одном месте и удобной выгрузке

Comment: Всё это уже есть в Prometheus, наверное?